# How to check if NOT NULL constraint exists

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am modifying a SQL table through C# code and I need to drop a NOT NULL constraint if it exists.  How do I check to see if it exists first?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select is_nullable 
from   sys.columns
where  object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename')  
and    name = 'columnname';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could check `syscolumns.isnullable` flag? Or more recently:

```
COLUMNPROPERTY(@tableId, 'ColumnName', 'AllowsNull')
```

Where @tableId is OBJECT_ID('TableName')

Answer (score 1):

execute this SQL Statement:

```
select * from information_schema.columns c
inner join information_schema.tables t on c.table_catalog = t.table_catalog and t.table_schema = c.table_schema and t.table_name = c.table_name
where c.table_name = 'Categories' and c.Is_nullable = 'NO'
```

and then execute the ALTER statement that removes the "not null" constraint

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your business rules, so I could be wrong, but what you are proposing sounds like a bad idea.

If the NOT NULL constraint shouldn't exist, then remove it from the DB.  If it should exist, program around it.

If you actually do need to implement DDL to change tables, I'd write a stored procedure to do and call the stored procedure from C#.

Comment: I am dynamically updating a table based on selected values.  The end-user is defining this table so we are giving them tools (that they understand) to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can with the use of [COLUMNPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx):

SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('schemaName.TableName'), 'ColumnName', 'AllowsNull')